# How to read a specific file from a tar file using Windows?

Tags: python, pandas, tar

I have a tar file with several files compressed in it. I need to read one specific file (it is in csv format) using pandas. I tried to use the following code:

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open('my_files.tar', 'r:gz')
f = tar.extractfile('some_files/need_to_be_read.csv')

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(f.read())
```

but it throws up the following error:

```
OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type
```

on the last line of the code. How do I go about this to read this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `pandas.read_csv()`, you need to give it a filename or file-like object. `tar.extractfile()` returns a file-like object. Instead of reading the file into memory, pass the file to Pandas.

So remove the `.read()` part:

```py
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open('my_files.tar', 'r:gz')
f = tar.extractfile('some_files/need_to_be_read.csv')

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(f)
```